# Export results to excel

Tags: export, excel

I have the following problem solved in Mathematica

```
m=Table[For[i = 0, i <= .7, i = i + 0.1, 
  Print[NMinimize[{i*Abs[(E^-k*(N*p)^k)/k! - k^-g] + 
      i/3*Abs[p - N^-r] + (1 - (2*i)/3)*
       Abs[Log[N]/Log[N*p] - (A*Log[N - B] + CC)], A != 0, B != 0, 
     CC != 0, N > 0, k > 1, N <= 1000, k <= 100, N - k >= 0, 
     N - B > 0, BB, g > 2, g < 3, r > 0, r < 1, N^-r < 1, k/N < 1, 
     p <= 1}, {A, B, CC, N, k, g, r, p}, 
    Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"]]], {j, 1}]
```

I want to turn it into a form which can be exportable to excel. I tried:

```
m//TableForm
```

but doesn't work. Can you please help me?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6):

You should always try to post minimal working (or not working, but minimal anyway) examples:

```
m = Table[NMinimize[(x - i )^4 + (y - 2 i)^2 + 3 i, {x, y}], {i, 0, .7, .1}];
Export["c:\\test.xlsx", {#[[1]], x, y} /. #[[2]] & /@ m]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]